# How to exclude the "System" from a validation rule?

Tags: validation, system

[image]

I know I can add `$User.Id == '00550000000lxVg', false`, to a formula to exclude a specific user but I can't seem to figure out a UserID for "System". How do I exclude System from a validation rule?

Comment: does $User.Name = 'System' not work or perhaps $User.Name = 'Automated Process'?

Comment: When I check the syntax I get an error, "Error: Field Name does not exist. Check spelling."

Comment: I think I'm just going create a fake user for this.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing.  We DO have a "robot" user account for automation from outside of SF to get into the Org.

Comment: @AMM Creating a fake user with sysadmin access was the only workaround I could find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Salesforce support, there is no way to do this. I would up creating a dummy account.

Answer (score 0):

There is a user created behind the scenes for the System user. You can query for the user's ID (select id, name from user where lastname= 'System') and then exclude from the validation.